# Spring 4 Controller String to XML Response

Tags: xml, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have @RestController that returns a json response if there are errors otherwise on a successful response returns an xml file for download.  My xml is a String and I sending the response back as:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + "myfile.xml" + "\"")
            .body(xmlAsString);
```

However, when I test it the content is returned as a string and not as an xml file - the entire xml portion is wrapped in quotes "" and all the quotes in the doc is escaped

I tried to set the .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) but that did not help.

How do I return a xml string from a spring controller method as a xml?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the attribute `produces` to have the value `MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE` because your POST API will respond the XML text content.

```java
@RestController
public class XmlController {

  @PostMapping(path = "/download", produces = {MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE}, consumes = {MediaType.ALL_VALUE})
  public ResponseEntity<String> download() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
      .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
      .body(
          "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\r\n" + 
          "<Student>\r\n" + 
          "    <age>32</age>\r\n" + 
          "    <name>John</name>\r\n" + 
          "</Student>"
      );
   }
}
```

Best,